# How to multiply a RealVector by a RealMatrix?

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

How can I multiply a given `RealVector` by a `RealMatrix`? I can't find any "multiply" method on both classes, only `preMultiply` but it seems not work:

```
// point to translate
final RealVector p = MatrixUtils.createRealVector(new double[] {
        3, 4, 5, 1
});

// translation matrix (6, 7, 8)
final RealMatrix m = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(new double[][] {
        {1, 0, 0, 6},
        {0, 1, 0, 7},
        {0, 0, 1, 8},
        {0, 0, 0, 1}
});

// p2 = m x p
final RealVector p2 = m.preMultiply(p);
// prints {3; 4; 5; 87}
// expected {9; 11; 13; 1}
System.out.println(p2);
```

Please compare the actual result with the expected result.

Is there also a way for multiplying a `Vector3D` by a 4x4 `RealMatrix` where the w component is throw away? (I'm looking not for custom implementation but an already existing method in the library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preMultiply` does not give you `m x p` but `p x m`. This would be suitable for your question but not for your comment `// p2 = m x p`.

To get the result you want you have two options:

1. Use `RealMatrix#operate(RealVector)` which produces `m x p`:

   ```
   RealVector mxp = m.operate(p);    
   System.out.println(mxp);
   ```
2. Transpose the matrix before pre-multiplying:

   ```
   RealVector pxm_t = m.transpose().preMultiply(p);
   System.out.println(pxm_t);
   ```

Result:

> {9; 11; 13; 1}

Comment: Thanks, I don't expect such a method name :)