# How do I postmultiply a RealMatrix by a RealVector (org.apache.commons commons-math3)

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

I am trying to do some analytic geometry using Java after having done a lot of my work in blender and python.

After poking around a bit, I think I should be using [org.apache.commons commons-math3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/linear.html) .

But then I tried to compute `M*v` and hit a roadblock. The `RealMatrix` class has a `.multiply(RealMatrix)` and a `.preMultiply(RealVector)`, but no `.multiply(RealVector)` (I asked for version 3.6 in my `pom.ml`).

The possibilities I can think of are

- I am missing something that should be obvious ;
- This library is immature ;
- I (and the rest of the blender community) are weird for doing my matrix multiplication backwards ;
- I should be using a different library.

How do I accomplish matrix-vector postmultiplication using the comons-math3 library?  Any suggestions about using a "better" library are welcome in comments, but are not answers to this question.

Comment: And how did I miss http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275669/how-to-multiply-a-realvector-by-a-realmatrix?s=6|1.3788 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method you are looking for is actually called [`operate(v)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html#operate%28org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealVector%29):

> Returns the result of multiplying this by the vector `v`.

This method will multiply a `RealMatrix` with the given `RealVector` and return the resulting `RealVector`.